# Wrong location of my system.exit code

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have an exit button on my user form and I think I have the code for it in the wrong spot because it doesn't work.  I've tried moving it around, but have had no luck.  It's toward the bottom of the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.*;

public class DayGUI extends JFrame {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JButton cmdGood;
    private JButton cmdBad;
    private JButton cmdAverage;
    private JButton cmdExit;

    public DayGUI()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("How are you feeling today?");

        cmdGood = new JButton("Good");
         cmdGood.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        cmdBad = new JButton("Bad");
         cmdBad.setBackground(Color.RED);

         cmdAverage = new JButton("Average");
         cmdAverage.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

         cmdExit = new JButton("Exit");
         cmdExit.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        Container c = mainFrame.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        c.add(cmdGood);
        c.add(cmdBad);
        c.add(cmdAverage);
        c.add(cmdExit);

        cmdGood.setMnemonic('G');
        cmdBad.setMnemonic('B');
        cmdAverage.setMnemonic('A');
        cmdExit.setMnemonic('E');

        mainFrame.setSize(280, 100);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });

        ButtonsHandler bhandler = new ButtonsHandler();
        cmdGood.addActionListener(bhandler);
        cmdBad.addActionListener(bhandler);
        cmdAverage.addActionListener(bhandler);
        cmdExit.addActionListener(bhandler);
        mainFrame.show();
        }
    class ButtonsHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)      
        {       
            if (e.getSource() == cmdGood)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Today is a good day!",
                        "I'm Feeling Happy!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            else if (e.getSource() == cmdBad)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm having a bad day today!",
                        "I'm Feeling Sad!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            else if (e.getSource() == cmdAverage)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm having an average day!",
                        "I'm Feeling In The Middle", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    private void cmdExit_pressed(){
        System.exit(0);
        }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new DayGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: `cmdExit_pressed`... spot the ASP developer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method you handle 3 different event source (`cmdGood`, `cmdBad`, `cmdAverage`), but you don't handle `cmdExit`, even though it uses the same `ActionListener`. Add the handling of that source in the same way you handle the other 3.

Comment: In other words, `cmdExit_pressed` is never used in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have no clause for `cmdExit` inside your `actionPerformed` method.  Add one:

```
else if (e.getSource() == cmdExit)
    cmdExit_pressed();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason was already explained (`cmdExit_pressed` is never used). Here is a way your program would be written nearer to today's standards:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.*;

public class DayGUI extends JFrame {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JButton cmdGood;
    private JButton cmdBad;
    private JButton cmdAverage;
    private JButton cmdExit;

    public DayGUI()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("How are you feeling today?");

        cmdGood = new JButton("Good");
        cmdGood.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        cmdBad = new JButton("Bad");
        cmdBad.setBackground(Color.RED);

        cmdAverage = new JButton("Average");
        cmdAverage.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        cmdExit = new JButton("Exit");
        cmdExit.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        Container c = mainFrame.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        c.add(cmdGood);
        c.add(cmdBad);
        c.add(cmdAverage);
        c.add(cmdExit);

        cmdGood.setMnemonic('G');
        cmdBad.setMnemonic('B');
        cmdAverage.setMnemonic('A');
        cmdExit.setMnemonic('E');

        mainFrame.setSize(280, 100);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
            });

        cmdGood.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed() {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Today is a good day!",
                                                  "I'm Feeling Happy!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            });
        cmdBad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed() {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm having a bad day today!",
                                                  "I'm Feeling Sad!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            });
        cmdAverage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed() {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm having an average day!",
                                                  "I'm Feeling In The Middle", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            });
        cmdExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed() {
                    System.exit();
                }
            });

        mainFrame.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new DayGUI();
    }
}
```

This way each button gets his own ActionListener, and you don't have to do this `if (source == ...)` comparisons.

Even better would be using `Action` objects (i.e. anonymous subclasses of AbstractAction) here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cmdExit_pressed` isn't being called by anything. Why were you expecting it to be?

All actions have to be handled through the `ActionListener` interface.

I strongly suggest that you have a separate `ActionListener` per button, rather than one for them all with a if/else loop inside.

Answer (score 0):

Er, that part is fine.

The problem is you don't give that button an `ActionListener`